# Installing Ubuntu so that you can only boot from BIOS?

Tags: boot

I am looking to dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu. I already have Windows 10 on my laptop, and have installed Ubuntu on my desktop so that it asks me at every startup what OS I would like to boot. I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop but I want it to just boot straight to Windows every time without even giving me the option to boot Linux. My laptop has a button to boot into a boot selection menu so I want to only be able to get into the Linux in that way. Any way I can do this?

Comment: What kind of a laptop do you have and can you please add a picture of your bios screen?

Comment: This is a feature of your BIOS and not Ubuntu. The solution varies by bios

Comment: I have a Lenovo Yoga 3 14. It has a button on the side where you can press it when the computer is off and then it automatically asks if you want to go into the BIOS, Boot Selection, or Recovery.

Answer (score 0):

It's geekly but with in Windows there is way to reprogram the Master Boot Record for this. This is easier to do desktops since you can have 2 or more hard drives an use that button to the OS. In may case I have my desktop set-up so Windows 10 and Ubuntu are installed in a way were they don't know about the older OS. The UFI is set-up to always go 1st to the DVD-ROM Drive and then the Windows 10 disk. If I what to go into Ubuntu I suntdown Windows 10 hold the esc key on restart then pick the Linux drive.